# Django Translation on Heroku is not fully working

Tags: python, django, heroku, gettext

I deployed my Django app on Heroku and I added `https://github.com/piotras/heroku-buildpack-gettext.git` this ugettext buildpack and some parts of the application are note translated. Locally it's working, I don't know where is the issue coming from.

For example, the menu item **Classes Types** is not translated but other parts are.

`{% trans "Class Types" %}`

### template

```
{% load i18n %}
....
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{% trans "Class Types" %}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'class_type-list' %}">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> {% trans "All" %}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'class_type-new' %}">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> {% trans "New" %}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
....
```

### ar/LC_MESSAGES.po

```
#: templates/back_office/class_type_list.html:4
#: templates/back_office/menu.html:37
msgid "Class Types"
msgstr "انواع الحلقات"
```

### en/LC_MESSAGES.po

```
#: templates/back_office/class_type_list.html:4
#: templates/back_office/menu.html:37
msgid "Class Types"
msgstr "Class Types"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate those files during the build.

Add a post compile file in `bin/post_compile` (no extension like procfile) with the following line:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

Optionally you can add the specific language (e.g. `python manage.py compilemessages -l nl`)

[Since Heroku 20](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/198#issuecomment-185169313), gettext is automatically added for the default Python build package. This is only during build and not at runtime. Therefore the command should be added in `post_compile` and not under `release:` in the `procfile`.

Older info links to buildpacks for `gettext` on Heroku (e.g. in the question above). Those are not needed anymore with this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found it's better to commit the compiled messages files (***.mo**) to Heroku, and translation will work properly.