# Heroku - Django - Translation not working in production

Tags: django, heroku, internationalization

I am trying to translate some static text with a Django app.

It works on my local, but not on production. I use Heroku.

**What I did:**

After doing some research it seems to be partly because .mo is in my .gitignore.py.

However, I read a few times that this should remain as such and instead automate compile messages in an app.json file. Which is what I did below:

**app.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
      "release": "python manage.py compilemessages"
    },
    }
```

**procfile**

```
release: python manage.py compilemessages
web: daphne mysite.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

With the 'gettext' buildpack added to Heroku, I did manage to see a large push of lines contained in my local .mo file on the production logs.

However, I cannot seem to be able to render them.

I can clearly see the .mo files when running:

```
heroku run bash -a appname 

find . -name "*.mo"
```

**edit##**

```
However whe running 
heroku run bash -a appname 
cd locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
ls
```

I only see the below and no .mo file on sight.

```
~/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES $ ls
django.po
```

This makes me think that my script i app.jso is not working properly.

Questions:

1. Should I simply remove the .mo from .gitignore to fix the issue?
2. Am I right to continue on the current path and find a solution without
   removing .mo from .gitignore?

Comment: "I read a few times that this should remain as such and instead automate compile messages in an app.json file"—where did you see this? I don't think you want a `release` command here (as you seem to have discovered yourself) since the generated files won't be included in your application slug.

Comment: I found this advice several times on this forum, in the comment section when people had similar problem than me. Note the comment was to have the automation of 'compilemessages' not having 'release' in procfile: that was ,my mistake, since I moved it to bin/post_compile it seems to all work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found the answer.

The problem is related to Heroku 20 stack.

**My error:**

Instead of having a `Procfile` that looks like this:
**Procfile (old)**

```
release: python manage.py compilemessages
web: daphne mysite.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

**The solution:**

STEP 1

I should have left it as is:

Procfile (now)

```
web: daphne mysite.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

I removed `release: python manage.py compilemessages`

STEP 2

Create a folder called "bin" in my root directory (top level directory, where all folders are visible) and create a file called "post_compile" with no extension.

Inside this `post_compile` file, I wrote the following line:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

and it worked.

The answer was explained here:[Django Translation on Heroku is not fully working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743234/django-translation-on-heroku-is-not-fully-working/67096218#67096218)